# How to save a webpage that gets translated to English by Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, save, translation, html

Take any Chinese page - say http://www.worldjournal.com/

When I open it in Google Chrome, It translates it to English. I want to save it (ideally in Word or PDF, but HTML may just do) and sent it to my colleague in English. If I save the page as-is, Google Chrome saves it in Chinese and not English. Any way to save it in English instead?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 9, accepted):

- If you save the page as 'Webpage, Complete', it saves the translated page as well as other files related to it, e.g. images, etc...
- If you save the page as 'Webpage, HTML Only', it will simply get the web page's source code (which obviously remains unchanged after translating it using a web service).

Comment: Here it seems there is a trick. I have to scroll down to end of the page and right-click save.

Answer (score 6):

After translation by Google Translate, you get your article.
The translated article is preceded by a small header which says GOOGLE etc.
Then "Translate from  ..French..  to  ..English..   "

Next you have your article below.

If you print it with the normal printing.  All you have is just page 1 and nothing more.

Now do this ( In Firefox).
Move the cursor to somewhere in the article body, not the area in the GOOGLE header.
Do a right-click.
There will be a pop-up, and among them there is a 'This Frame'.
Click on 'This Frame', you get another popup.
Click on the 'Show only this Frame'.

Ok, now the Google header is gone, you see only the translated article.

Now you can print your translated article to printer or PDF generator.

Answer (score 1):

1. After the page has been translated
2. do a ctrl-a to highlight everything
3. do a ctrl-c to copy
4. open up a new email and address it to yourself
5. subject: name what the page is about
6. in the body of the email do a ctrl-v to paste your page
7. hit send
8. open up your email and find your just sent to yourself email.
   Hint: find the subject that you just named this page
9. click on the print icon
10. change how the page should be printed to pdf file
11. click send (or however your pdf says)
12. save your new pdf file wherever you want.

Answer (score 0):

There is a simpler method if you do not need drawings, only text content. The format is very decent

1. Right click - select all
2. copy
3. paste to blank rtf file on your desktop